# ZF Natural Even Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Regarding $\Bbb N$ as constructed using ZF ($0=\emptyset, n+1=n^+=n\cup\{n\}$), how is the property "divisible by 2" expressed (using sets and logic)?

Comment: Both answers are beautiful.. I don't now which one to check as the 'correct' answer!! :)

Comment: Typically, one favors the first answer in the case of equally good answers. You can always upvote both, though.

Comment: Choice eh? Got it. :) (Of course I up-voted both)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define addition and multiplication on the natural numbers as defined. $m+n$ is defined to be the unique $k$ such that there is a bijection between $k$ and $m\times\{0\}\cup n\times\{1\}$. Similarly $m\cdot n=k$ when $k$ is the unique natural number such that $m\times n$ has a bijection with $k$.

Now we can say that $\exists k(k+k=n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way to go about it is to define arithmetic on $\Bbb N,$ explicitly or by recursion. Then we define evenness in the usual way.

Alternatively (and a bit more cumbersomely), define $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ by $f(n)=(n^+)^+.$ Now, given any $n\in\Bbb N,$ define $f^0(n)=n,$ and define $f^{m+1}(n)=f\bigl(f^m(n)\bigr).$ By recursion, we have that $f^m:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ for all $m\in\Bbb N.$ We can then say that $n$ is even if and only if $n=f^m(0)$ for some $m\in\Bbb N.$